# how to create event on input in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have input on form text, I want to see the input in the log using what event key?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" //event>
```

in this text for example I type

```
"seat"

then the console log appears
s
se
sea
seat
```

Comment: you can also [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) the model, (which your want to add anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach event handler and print out log as shown in the js fiddle below. Open the browser dev tool console tab and check.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7nfdyvgm)

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
   return {
     inputValue: null,
   }
  },
  methods: {
    inputChange(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  }
})

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :value="inputValue" @input="inputChange" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` element fires 2 useful events when edited:

1. The `input` event is fired every time the value of the element changes.
2. The `change` event fires when the value is committed, for example pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a dropdown list, etc.

In your case for a `text` input element where you want every keypress, the `input` event is what you need:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" @input="inputEvent">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Answer (score 0):

Maybe vue watcher is that where you looking for.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>      
      <input v-model="value" placeholder="hi">      
    </p> 
    <p>value: {{ value }} </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'hey',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
  },  
  methods: {
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Most of the time "*@input*" is not necessary** and can be better replaced by **v-model** and **watch** as pointed by [@Maik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70558474/12975352) (more in line with vue best practices). However, if you have a specific context and want to access the input value::

```
methods: {
     handleInput(evt: any) {
         console.log(evt.target.value)
     }
}

@input="handleInput"
```